# Application of the fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: number-theory

I'm just going through my lecture notes and under one subheading "application", I have written:

> If $m = \prod_{i = 1}^k p_i^{r_i}$ and $n = \prod_{i = 1}^k p_i^{s_i}$, for primes $p_i$ & $r_i, s_i \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\gcd(m,n) = \prod_{i = 1}^k p_i^{\min(r_i,s_i)}$ and $\mathrm{lcm}(m,n) = \prod_{i = 1}^k p_i^{\min(r_i,s_i)}$.

Should they both be $\min(r_i,s_i)$, because this just gives gcd = lcm doesn't it?

Comment: The second is a typo for max

Comment: Do you mean the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)?

Comment: @JonasMeyer I swear my lecturer said that but then she (definitely) wrote "algebra" on the board, so I just thought maybe it has two names?

Comment: Just googled Fundamental Theorem of Algebra and it is nothing like theory of arithmetic lol.

Comment: @Kaish: Please: TeX is sophisticated.  Write \prod_{i=1}^k, not \Pi_{i=1}^k.  These don't look the same $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^k$ versus $\displaystyle\Pi_{i=1}^k$.  Also, don't write \mathrm{min}; just write \min.  Look: $\displaystyle\min_{a\in A} f(a)$ versus $\displaystyle\mathrm{min}_{a\in A} f(a)$. The latter form also fails to provide proper spacing before and after, as in $a\min b$.  And \gcd is also a standard operator name in LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is a typo, it should read $\max$.

**Remark:** The factorization result mentioned in the post is called the Fundamental Theorem of *Arithmetic*, or the Unique Factorization Theorem.

The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra has various statements. One of them is that a non-constant polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$, the set of complex numbers, always has a root in $\mathbb{C}$.

It *can* be viewed as a factorization theorem, because it is equivalent to the result that a polynomial of degree $\ge 1$ over $\mathbb{C}$ can be expressed as a product of linear polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thought so. Thank you.